# How to remove special character ” in a string by PHP?

Tags: php, character

I have some string like this

> FloraFlex Flora Pipe Fitting, elbow, 1Â” FloraFlex FloraCap

I want to remove the character ”. This is ”, not ". Do you have any idea? Thank you.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "special character". There are only characters, lot's of them, but they are all equal.

Comment: What is your actual question here? If you want to replace that specific character, then do so.

Comment: So just replace it! What other idea do you need?

Comment: But when I get it only shows ", and I don't want to remove it :(

Comment: Removing is not replacing. You will need to be much more precise in stating what it actually is you have (use a hexeditor to find out...), what you actually want and what your actual problem to achieve that is. Otherwise we cannot help, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `str_replace` function

```
echo str_replace("”", '', "FloraFlex Flora Pipe Fitting, elbow, 1Â” FloraFlex FloraCap");
```

Comment: Thank you. Now the issue is when I get the text from CSV the ”, what I get is ". Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = str_replace('”', '', 'FloraFlex Flora Pipe Fitting, elbow, 1Â” FloraFlex FloraCap');
echo $result;
```

just copy that special character and paste it into str_replace function

sandbox example http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a1f08b831ef6bcbc26be18e37b61763fe12a3199

Answer (score 1):

In php whatever the character is in a string, you can replace it with php's builtin string function.

```
  $your_string = "FloraFlex Flora Pipe Fitting, elbow, 1Â” FloraFlex FloraCap";
  $search_character = "”";  
  $replace_with = "";
  $new_string = str_replace($search_character, $replace_with, $your_string);
```

Comment: Thank @infomasud. Now the issue is when I get the text from CSV the ”, what I get is ". Do you have any idea?

Comment: again use str_replace function . you can pass an array of symbols to search in a string. $search_symbols = array('a','b','c'); read more here  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php